# Can I use teamcity 7.1.4 with intellij 14?

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity

I am using teamcity 7.1.4 with intellij 14.

I would like to use the teamcity plugin from the settings page, to do remote runs.

Is it possible to do so?  Currently intellij stops and company's about

Failed to collect suitable build configurations : argument 0 for @notnull parameter of ...BuildServerManager .getSuitableConfigurations must not be null.

Comment: Can you please post a complete stacktrace?